# No property <method name> found for type <entityName>

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
@Data
public class MyTable implements java.io.Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 3879471087851341216L;

@Id
@Column(name = "MY_ID")
private BigInteger myId;

@Column(name = "ANOTHER_COL")
private String anotherColumn;
```

Then I create my repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MyTableRepository extends JpaRepository<MyTable, BigInteger> {

@Query(name = "select count(*) from MyTable where ...")
public Long getCountOf(@Param("myId") BigInteger myId);
```

But I receive, at the start:

> No property getCountOf found for type MyTable

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need to provide an explicit query. Spring-data-jpa can generate it for you. Simply try to replace your method with `long countByMyId(BigInteger myId);`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the naming of the method is misleading spring-jpa.

Also spring-data can auto-generate the count query for you, you don't need to provide it, provided that you follow the correct naming convention:

```
@Repository
public interface MyTableRepository extends JpaRepository<MyTable, BigInteger> {

    long countByMyId(BigInteger myId);
}
```

Comment: It seems it happens for each name...I tried calling the method "example" and the problem is still there